# Free, online way to convert a PDF (formulated by LaTeX) to an editable Word document?

Tags: fonts, pdf, windows, links, online

I know there's many free ways to convert PDF's to Word documents, however the ones that I have found have converted the fonts incorrectly, the table of contents is misaligned and none of the internal links work. Does anyone know how to fix this? The PDF is 22 pages.

Comment: Converting from PDF to editable formats like .doc or .odt, or even back to .tex can't be done perfectly - your only chance is manualy fixing what is wrong. The PDF format loses a lot of information, messes with whitespace to get it perfect and so on - it looks beautiful, but it's not intended to be editable.

Wrong font and few misaligments is actually a pretty good result.

Comment: You'll have much better luck starting w/ the original Word .doc. If you don't have access to that, why are you concerned about it? Tell the person who made the .pdf and leave it at that.

Comment: Why not use Adobe acrobat pro, this allows you to directly edit your PDF file? If you only need to change small parts, it's suitable.

Comment: @user23127 Er... budgetary limitations? Why not use it...? Several hundred pounds/euros/dollars worth of reasons...? And that is assuming that somebody is using one of the OS s for which it is even an expensive option.

Comment: Starting with the original `.tex` document is the better idea... @WillAdams.

Comment: Yes, whatever the original is, that's where to start.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't part of the question as originally framed, which allowed one to assume it was a Word .doc.

Comment: Fonts cannot be preserved during conversion. PDF includes fonts used in it embedded, but only partially embedded: only those characters used in the document. What happens when you want to use a different character during editing and you have not the font installed?